# Excel 2016 : Issue with CHAR(10) i.e New line

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have a data in excel, example shown below

```
Column1 (Cell A1)
A

B
```

[image]

**P.S.** - The value shown above are in 1 single cell and not 3 rows. (So, Char(10) is like a blank line cell value looks like below)

I need to remove the new line characters (Blanks) in between that cell value.

Output example,

```
Column1
A       
B
```

There are number of cells like this in my column.

My efforts:

I tried to do this with replace/substitute the Char(10) character but that removes all Char(10) and I get wrong output,

```
SUBSTITUTE(Column1,CHAR(10),"")
```

Wrong output:

```
Column1
AB
```

Could anyone please suggest a solution to achieve this? I can try something else as well to resolve this issue.

Comment: Any spaces in the values? Important to know if this can be a very easy answer or not.

Answer (score 2):

In `A1`, enter A and B with multiple line break in between

In `B1`, enter formula with resulted in only left one line break in between :

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A2,CHAR(10)," "))," ",CHAR(10))
```

Remark : To format the cell with Wrap Text

[image]

Comment: Strange - it does not work on my Windows PC - O365. Even `="A"&CHAR(10)&"B"` generates AB.

Comment: @markfitzpatrick you need to format the cell with word wrap.

Answer (score 0):

I would think:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10)&CHAR(10),CHAR(10))
```

and as @Rory recommended - turn on Wrap Text on the cell from the Alignment menu.

Comment: Thanks Everyone the solution worked, we can mark this query resolved. Thanks much!

Comment: @RahultheDFSScout - to mark it resolved, you have to mark it as Answered. Choose the answer that works for you and that will do the job.